# Find the memory location of variables using assembly language

Tags: assembly, machine-code

Hello m new to assembly language. I am trying to get the memory location for variables m using DOSBOX and MASM compilor  Here is the code

```
     .model small
   .stack 100H
 .data
   VARA BYTE 10   ;address is DS:xxxx
 VARB BYTE 0BH  ;address is DS:xxxx+1
 VARC WORD ?
   VARD SBYTE ?
   VARE DWORD ? 
   ARR BYTE 20 DUP(?)
  VARF SWORD 010B
  ARRB WORD 10 DUP(?)
  VARZ BYTE 0
 .CODE
  MAIN PROC
    mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ax,offset VARA
mov ah,09
int 21h

mov ax,offset VARB
mov ah,09
int 21h


    mov ax,offset VARC
mov ah,09
int 21h

    mov ax,offset VARD
mov ah,09
int 21h


    mov ax,offset VARE
mov ah,09
int 21h


mov ax,offset ARR
mov ah,09
int 21h


    mov ax,offset VARF
mov ah,09
int 21h

    mov ax,offset ARRB
mov ah,09
int 21h

mov ax,offset VARZ
mov ah,09
int 21h


mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

How can i find the memory address for all these variables? U can see the error in the image

[image]

Comment: You may try to compile it with `/L` command line option for MASM to generate listing file, where I think the addresses will be visible too (in form of offsets in data segment, the absolute true physical address is not known until the binary is loaded into memory and dynamically linked to it's target position from loader).

Comment: About error: change `VARA BYTE 10` (size specifier) to `VARA DB 10` ("define byte" directive), etc (`DW` for `WORD` and `SWORD`, `DD` for `DWORD`) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f6k0he8.aspx

Comment: @ped7g after correcting this to db there are no errors but there is no output on the screen

Comment: Thats' correct, you call the ah,9 in wrong way. Re-read the other comments from davmac answer until you understand them.

Comment: BTW, I read the MSDN MASM docs for a short while, and the `BYTE` way of defining byte is *correct* in modern MASM, but as you work under DOS with old DOS version of MASM, it knows only `DB` as "define byte". You should try to get somewhere the old DOS MASM manual to avoid such confusion in the future.

Comment: I read the davmac comments and by mov dx,ax i print the value then it prints 16 special characters instead of printing memory location value

Comment: mov ds,ax
 mov dx,offset VARA
 mov ax,09
 int 21h

Comment: Thats my code @Ped7g

Comment: yes, that's correct. `dx` contains address to string. So if you do `mov dx,offset VARA`, it will display bytes `10, 0bh, ...` (as string) till it finds byte `'$'` by accident. I will copy the relevant comment here again: *"DOS doesn't have "display number" function, only display string (ah=9). Search SO how to convert number into string"*

Comment: If you know C, you want to do: `sprintf(string_buffer, "%p", &VARA_value)` -> you have the address (`OFFSET VARA` is correct way to get offset part of real mode address, `SEG VARA` is way to get the segment part of VARA address) ... and now you need your own `printf` code. Then you can use the `ah=9, int 21h` to print the prepared `string_buffer`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `OFFSET` modifier, eg:

```
mov ax, OFFSET VARA
```

to load the address of `VARA` into the `ax` register. You can also use the `LEA` instruction to achieve the same thing:

```
lea ax, VARA
```

Comment: thanx should i use this for every variable or for just VarA and then increment to get the other addresses ?

Comment: kindly let me know what can i do ?

Comment: @abd both can work. If you know the relative addresses of the variables, sure, just increment to get the other addresses. Personally I'd just load each address separately.

Comment: lea ax, ARR                                                                                             mov ah,09
 int 21h   prints the memory location where ARR ids stored

Comment: @abd `lea ax,ARR` `mov ah,09` looks like bug. You know the `ax` consists of `ah` (high 8 bits) and `al` (low 8 bits)? So the `lea` will load `ax` with address, and next `mov ah,9` will damage that value.

Comment: .data
   VARA BYTE 10   ;address is DS:xxxx
   .CODE
  MAIN PROC
        mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 mov ax,offset VARA
 mov ah,09
 int 21h

Comment: @Ped7g kindly let me know

Comment: @davmac kindly let me know about it

Comment: @abd please don't post comments that just say "kindly let me know". It's just noise. We already get the first comment, you don't need to post another.

Comment: @abd it's not clear what you're asking. I don't understand what it is that you want to know.

Comment: I want to print all the above variable memory addresses but ai got an error undefined variables

Comment: i paste my code in above comment so can u correct this

Comment: @abd printing an address would involve first converting it into a string of characters and then issuing the DOS request (the INT 21h/AH=09h that you refer to) with the DX register containing the address of the string. The details of how to do that are more complex than can be explained in comments here. Furthermore if you are getting an error during assembly you need to post the exact code you are trying to assemble and the exact text of the error message, in the question - not in a comment.

Comment: @abd in the new version you again store value in `ax` and then right away change the `ah`. One more time: `ax` = `ah * 256 + al`. If you change `ah`, you change also `ax` (and `eax` in 32b and `rax` in 64b)! `ax` and `ah` are the same register (just different/overlapping bits). Also DOS doesn't have "display number" function, only display string (ah=9). Search SO how to convert number into string (I would personally prefer hexadecimal formatting, I'm used to it from debugger and also 16b values can have fixed 4 char width (0000-FFFF), while decimal may need 5 chars for big numbers (0-65535)).

Comment: U can see the image for Error,which says that Variable is not defined